# joomla 3.2 module helper.php

Tags: php, joomla, module

I'm doing a module for joomla 3.2,I'm trying to pass a variable from one function to another in the same class, the purpose is to use it in a query.

How can I pass the "$result" variable in the query of the function due() ?

```
<?php
class modUno
{     
    public static function Uno()
    {   
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();   
        $query = "SELECT id AS memTotal FROM #__users WHERE username = 'bruno';";

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->query();
        return $result->fetch_object()->memTotal;
    }

    public static function due()
    {
        $result->due();

        $db = JFactory::getDBO();   
        $query = "SELECT avatar AS memTotal FROM #__comprofiler WHERE id = '$result';";

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $resulta = $db->query();
        return $resulta->fetch_object()->memTotal;
    }
}
?>
```

above is the "helper.php", then there's the "mod_chat.php", finally, there is "default.php"

mod_chat

```
enter code here

<?php

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/helper.php' );

$risultato = modUno::uno();
$foto = modUno::due();
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_chat');
?>
```

default.php

```
enter code here


<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' ); ?>

<p> risultato: <?php echo $risultato; ?></p>
<p> foto:<img src="http://somesite.com/images/comprofiler/<?php echo $foto; ?>" /></p>
```

returns errors !

Comment: On a side note, please have a look at the following link for your database query http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase ;) Also be sure to use `execute()` rather than `query()`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is a PHP question, not a Joomla question. I've found the PHP tutorial on codeacademy.com to be an excellent resource for learning PHP.

Looks like you are trying to get a user's Community Builder avatar. You should not be using direct database queries here. Use Community Builder data API to get what you need. Read more about it here - 
https://www.joomlapolis.com/support/tutorials/120-api-usage/18361-obtaining-field-values-through-getfields-api (see the end of this article, the code for getting avatar is there)

If you wish to absolutely query the DB, rather than 2 different functions, you should make just 1 and use a JOIN to get the user's avatar based on his Joomla username.

```
<?php
class modUno
{     
    public static function avatar()
    {   
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();   
        $query = "SELECT cb.avatar FROM #__comprofiler AS cb, #__users AS u 
        WHERE u.id=cb.user_id AND u.username = 'bruno'";

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadResult();
        return $result;
        //return $result->fetch_object()->memTotal;
    }
}
```

@Lodder - You should never be directly calling execute() when using select queries with Joomla.

As a side note - you need to use ModUno::due() instead of $result->due()

Comment: When I was referring to it, I was referring to `$db->execute()`, not actually `execute()`

Comment: I know. However you should not be calling $db->execute() either. Always use the wrapper functions like $db->loadObjectList()

Comment: When you are doing delete or update you need do $db->execute() so I wouldn't say "never." ;)   Reallhy if you are going to write a query write with the JDatabaseQuery API or use the CB API even better.